# Setting up a whitelist in a python telegram bot

Tags: python

I'm writing a telegram bot, and I have a problem with adding a whitelist.
My old method for it to work is really simple;

`whitelist = []`

and then

`if chat_id not in whitelist:`

And it worked good so far. But some friends wanted this bot for their personal use, so I wanted to upgrade it a bit and add two commands to add and remove users from a list in a file called "whitelist.txt". But now, for some reason, it cannot read any Telegram IDs from the list. Here's how I made it;

```
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    username = update.message.chat.username
    with open("whitelist.txt", 'r') as whitelist:
        if chat_id not in whitelist:
            update.message.reply_text('Unauthorised user!')
            print(f'User {username} ({chat_id}) tried issuing a command but was not allowed.')
```

I added two lines at the end of that part of the code to see what does the list looks like when it's reading it, and it prints out this;

`['1234567890']` (not actually my Telegram ID. But that's how it shows it.)

Now, what I think the problem is is that, it's trying to compare my ID, 1234567890, with the one it's reading off the list. On the .txt file, it's showing as 1234567890 with nothing else around it, but on the Python console, it prints out as this thing with brackets and the \n, so it doesn't work.

I'm not that knowledgable in Python and I don't really know how could I Google this, I'm sorry if the answer is super dumb and simple, but I do appreciate the help nonetheless.

Edit: I figured that maybe sharing the command that adds Telegram IDs to the whitelist.txt would be useful, so, here is it:

```
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    if chat_id == admin_id:
        add_id = update.message.text.split(" ")[1]
        with open("whitelist.txt", 'w') as f:
            f.write(f'{add_id}')
            f.close()
            update.message.reply_text(f'ChatID `{add_id}` has been added!')
```

the `admin_id` is an ID that isn't changable by any text file, and it's kinda the highest power of the bot. Allows it to use commands no one else can, and basically links the bot's important commands to one specific Telegram ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use the `in` like this on files. You should first read the file content with [`.read()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) and only then process it.

So the final result will look like this:

```py
chat_id = update.message.chat_id
username = update.message.chat.username

with open("whitelist.txt", 'r') as whitelist:
    whitelist_content = whitelist.read()
    if chat_id not in whitelist_content:
        update.message.reply_text('Unauthorised user!')
        print(f'User {username} ({chat_id}) tried issuing a command but was not allowed.')
```

Comment: It now gives me the error `'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int`, weirdly enough.

Comment: @BasilGakami try with this: `if str(chat_id) not in whitelist_content:`

Comment: Ayy! It worked! I thought str() wasn't the solution because I did ```str(chat_id) = update.message.chat_id```, thank you so much!